# How to only have a Y axes representing data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axes

I want to plot 'Times of goals scored in your last match' data into a line chart in Chart.js.

I have a userGoalTime array e.g. `[34, 80, 90]`
I have an opponentGoalTime array e.g. `[39, 42]`

The Y axes will have all of the minutes but I don't want anything on the X axes. The problem is that I think chart.js has to represent a value with something on the X axes (if that makes sense)

Can anyone shed some light on how to plot points on a chart, using only the Y axes?

Attempted solution:

```
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['0', '1'], // I DON'T WANT THE X AXES TO REPRESENT ANYTHING
      datasets: [{
        label: 'For',
        backgroundColor: '#85CE36',
        fill: false,
        showLine: showLine, // this is true
        borderColor: '#85CE36',
        data: userGoals // The array as described
      }, {
        label: 'Against',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        fill: false,
        showLine: showLine, // this is true
        borderColor: 'red',
        data: opponentGoals // The array as described
      }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: nameOfStat
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
      },
      hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
      },
      elements: {
        point: {
          pointStyle: style
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false // Not really what I am looking for... This just hides the X axes but that's it
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options:
    {
        scales:
        {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false
            }]
        }
    }
});
```